# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{D}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

It is required to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on the open unit disc centered at $0$, i.e. $\mathbb{D}$. Clearly by virtue of the ratio test the series converges pointwise on  $\mathbb{D}$. However I find it difficult to see why the convergence is not uniform. Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: What is the set $\mathbb D$?

Comment: The open unit disc centered at zero.

Comment: Then you might want to include it in your post.

Comment: The series does not converge pointwise at $z=1$.

Comment: @Jack Sorry I thought it was standard notation. Anyway I included it now.

Comment: If the summation index is $i$, shouldn't there be an $i$ somewhere in the sum?

Comment: The series will diverge at $z=1$ so one expects to have problems as we approach this value.

Comment: How can convergence be uniform if $\lim_{z\to 1^-} f(z) = +\infty$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the uniform Cauchy test. Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1n\,\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^k\Bigr|\ge\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^{2n}\to e^{-2}>0.
$$

Comment: how do you know that the sum on the right greater than the quantity on the left? does not there is 1/n term that lessen each term of the sum?

Comment: @Idonotknow And there are $n$ terms in the sum.

Comment: so which is more stronger?

Comment: $n\times\frac1n=1$.

Comment: so it will never be greater than ? so why we are using greater than or = and not = only?

Comment: In fact it is $>$ (observe that the exponent $k$ on the LHS is changed to $2\,n$ on the RHS.). But if it is $>$, it is also $\ge$.