# Uniform convergence of $\frac{nz^n}{1}, \frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 7.22

> Where do the following sequences converge pointwise? Do they converge uniformly on this domain? (a)$\frac{nz^n}{1}$ (b) $\frac{z^n}{n}$ (c) $ \frac{1}{1+nz}$
>
> [image]

These sequences were asked about in these questions: [Uniform convergence of $\frac{1}{1+nz}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532220), [Where do the following sequences converge pointwise and uniformly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610950) and [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{D}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053980) , but I have other questions. ([(c) and (d) are here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871633))

Firstly, is this supposed to be unambiguous? I mean 'this domain' refer to the answers we got for pointwise convergence? Or are 7.22(a) and (b) missing specified 'domains', which I guess would be what (c) has? Anyhoo, I'm just gonna assume 'this domain' refer to the answers we got for pointwise convergence for (a) and (b).

(b1)

Pointwise convergence: I think $\lim \frac{z^n}{n} = 0 \iff |z| \le 1$?
Pf:
$$\lim |\frac{z^n}{n}| = \lim \frac{|z^n|}{n} = \lim \frac{|z|^n}{n} = 0 \iff |z| \le 1. \therefore, \lim \frac{z^n}{n} = 0 \iff |z| \le 1$$ QED

(b2)

Uniform convergence: I think $\lim \frac{z^n}{n} \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff$ also $|z| \le 1$ by Exer 7.19(a)? (*)

(a1)

Pointwise convergence: I think $\lim n z^n = 0 \iff |z| < 1$ as [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610950/), but is my reasoning below right?

Pf:

$$\lim |n z^n| = \lim n |z|^n = 0 \iff |z| \le 1. \therefore, \lim n |z|^n = 0 \iff |z| \le 1$$

QED

(a2)

Uniform convergence: $\lim n z^n \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff |z| \le r < 1$ as [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610950/), but is my reasoning below right?

Pf:

$|n z^n| = n |z|^n \le n r^n \to 0$ Conclude with Exer 7.19(a). (*)

QED

(a3)

Uniform convergence: $\lim n z^n \stackrel{u}{\ne 0} \iff |z| < 1?$

How exactly would we prove this?

- Just say that pointwise convergence to $0$ (or any $\mathbb C$-constant for that matter) doesn't hold on $|z|=1$?

I think I remember reading somewhere that uniform convergence is for closed sets or something so if it holds in $A$ then it should hold in $\overline{A} := A \cup \partial A$. I don't think this is in the text, or maybe I overlooked it. Might be assumed to be known from elementary analysis. I might be confusing this with uniform continuity.

- How would we show this by definition? I tried finding $\varepsilon$ s.t. $\forall N > 0, \exists z \in G: n > N \wedge n|z|^n \ge \varepsilon$ to no avail. Hints?

---

> (*)
>
> Exer 7.19(a)
>
> [image]
>
> Suppose $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ and $f_n: G \to \mathbb C, n \ge 1$. Then $\lim a_n =0, a_n \in \mathbb R, |fn(z)| \le a_n \ \forall z \in G \implies f_n \stackrel{u}{\to} 0 \ $ in G.

Comment: Honestly, I’m not sure how many different questions are here. Is it possible to go through and $(1)$ type the problems of the images you’ve posted, and $(2)$ separate any problems that are unrelated to the immediate question you are asking (there should be one, possibly two questions in a single post, but there appears to be several here).

Comment: To be frank, some of your questions have been a little hard to read, so I don't manage to finish reading them, and maybe I'm not the only one. In addition to Clayton's suggestions, if you must use non-standard notation e.g. $"0\iff |z|<1?"$ please explain what it means.

Comment: @Clayton Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinKhor Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with any of the proofs for the pointwise convergence. If you are allowed to claim e.g. $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|z^n|}{n} = 0 \iff |z|\leq 1$ then there is no point to the question at all. So you should justify this with a full argument. The fact that this is sloppy is also important when you find out that in the proof of $(a1)$, when you claim

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n z^n=0 \iff |z|\leq 1 $$
 you also claim in particular that $n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ by choosing $|z| = 1$. Curiously you copied correctly the answer from the other MSE post (strict inequality important.)

For the proofs of uniform convergence, the answers are right. But I don't like what you wrote because you did not explain how the exercise was used. This exercise talks about a sequence $a_n$. What is this sequence?

Finally, for $(a3)$, I have no idea what you are doing. It seems you use $\iff$ to not mean "if and only if", because $$\lim n z^n \stackrel{u}{\ne 0} \iff |z| < 1?$$ is $[A]$ redundant, since we already characterised the criteria for uniform convergence in $(a2)$ and $[B]$ not consistent with $(a2)$, if I understand you correctly. So the fact that you think $(a3)$ is needed means you don't understand your argument for $(a2)$, and I suggest you write it out in full, both "if" and "only if" directions. I also suggest you use less sentences made up purely of mathematical symbols.

Comment: Ummmm re pointwise I'm not claiming. I put a question mark and then put the proof below...wow I was so unclear. Thanks Calvin Khor!

Comment: @BCLC I've mentally discarded all question marks to understand it easier. I believe I am calling into question the proof underneath.

Comment: Edited. I'll analyse others later. Thanks!

Comment: @BCLC I think I've made what I was trying to say much clearer.

Comment: I don't think you were unclear to begin with =)

Comment: @BCLC it's just in case. :)