# Uniform convergence of $ \frac{1}{1+nz}$, and do we have 'piecewise' uniform convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 7.22

> Where do the following sequences converge pointwise? Do they converge uniformly on this domain? (a)$\frac{nz^n}{1}$ (b) $\frac{z^n}{n}$ (c) $ \frac{1}{1+nz}$
>
> [image]

These sequences were asked about in these questions: [Uniform convergence of $\frac{1}{1+nz}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532220), [Where do the following sequences converge pointwise and uniformly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610950) and [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{D}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053980) , but I have other questions. ([(a) and (b) are here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871294))

Firstly, is this supposed to be unambiguous? I mean 'this domain' refer to the answers we got for pointwise convergence? Or are 7.22(a) and (b) missing specified 'domains', which I guess would be what (c) has? Anyhoo, I'm just gonna assume 'this domain' refer to the answers we got for pointwise convergence for (c). I'm gonna try with the $\Re(z) \ge 0$ for (c2), (c3), (c7) and (c8) and then taking off $\Re(z) \ge 0$ in (c4), (c5), (c9) and (c10). Finally in relation to question (c), I have questions (d1)-(d4).

(c1)

Pointwise convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 1 \iff z=0?$

$$\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = \lim \frac{1}{1+n(0)} = \lim 1 = 1$$

(c2)

Pointwise convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 0 \iff |z| \ge r > 0, \Re(z) \ge 0, z \ne 0?$

$$\lim \frac{1}{|1+nz|} \stackrel{\Re(z) \ge 0}{\le} \lim \frac{1}{|nz|} \le \lim \frac{1}{n|z|} \le \lim \frac{1}{nr} = 0$$

Where do I use $z \ne 0$, whether or not this is wrong? If wrong, then which part and why?

(c3)

Pointwise convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 0 \iff \Re(z) \ge 0, z \ne 0?$

Deduced from previous (c2)? Equivalent to previous actually?

(c4)

Pointwise convergence: (I'm taking off $\Re(z) \ge 0$ in (c2))

$\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 0 \iff |z| \ge r > 0, z \ne 0?$

$$\lim |\frac{1}{1+nz}| = \lim \frac{1}{|1+nz|} \le \lim \frac{1}{|1-n|z||} \le \lim \frac{1}{|1-nr|} = 0$$

Where do I use $z \ne 0$, whether or not this is wrong? If wrong, then which part and why?

(c5)

Pointwise convergence: (I'm taking off $\Re(z) \ge 0$ in (c3))

$\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 0 \iff z \ne 0?$

Deduced from previous (c4)? Equivalent to previous actually?

(c6)

Uniform convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} \stackrel{u}{=} 1 \iff z=0$ trivially?

(c7)

Uniform convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff |z| \ge r > 0, \Re(z) \ge 0, z \ne 0?$

Bounded by a convergent sequence

(c8)

Uniform convergence: $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff \Re(z) \ge 0, z \ne 0?$

Also deduced from previous (c7)? Equivalent to previous actually?

(c9)

Uniform convergence: (I'm taking off $\Re(z) \ge 0$ in (c7))

$\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff |z| \ge r > 0, z \ne 0?$

Bounded by a convergent sequence

(c10)

Uniform convergence: (I'm taking off $\Re(z) \ge 0$ in (c8))

$\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} \stackrel{u}{=} 0 \iff z \ne 0?$

Also deduced from previous (c9)? Equivalent to previous actually?

(My own questions)

(d1)

Is it possible to have some function sequence uniformly convergent to $a \in \mathbb C$ on $A \subseteq \mathbb C$ and then $b \in \mathbb C$ on $B \subseteq \mathbb C$?

This arises from (c) where it seems like it's uniformly convergent to 1 at the point $z=0$ and then uniformly convergent to 0 at $\Re(z) \ge 0, z \ne =0$. This also arises from a mistake I made in (c) where I supposedly proved uniform convergence to 0 on $|z| \le 1$ (Then I wondered where I used $z \ne 0$ which led me to realise I was wrong).

(d2)

If yes to (d1) and in the case that $a \ne b$, then do we necessarily have that the function sequence is not uniformly convergent on $A \cup B$?

(d3)

If yes to (d1) and in that case that $a=b$, then is it possible that the function sequence is not uniformly convergent on $A \cup B$?

(d4)

Is there some kind of concept of 'piecewise' uniform convergence? I was thinking $N=N_1 1_{z \in A_1} + N_2 1_{z \in A_2}$ My understanding of uniform convergence that is $N$ is independent of $z$. I was thinking we define 'piecewise' for countable indices $K$: $N=\sum_{k \in K}N_k 1_{z \in A_k}$.

Comment: Hey, I don't know much about complex analysis but you put a qustion mark after $\lim \frac{1}{1+nz} = 1 \iff z=0$, so I tried to think about it; if you write $z = a+bi$ and multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate you get $\lim \dfrac {an+1}{(an+1)^2 - b^2} - \dfrac {b}{(an+1)^2 - b^2}i$ which more clearly goes to $0$.

Comment: @Ovi lol I was overthinking I guess. Thanks! That settles the pointwise convergence I guess. Then there's the uniform convergence

Comment: @Ovi. We have $|1/y|=1/|y|$  for any non-zero $y\in \Bbb C.$ And  we have $ |1+nz|\geq |nz|-|1|=n|z|-1.$  So if $z\ne 0$ then  for all $n>1/|z|$ we have $|1/(1+nz)|\leq 1/(n|z|-1). $

Answer (score 1):

I've not read whole of your post, but apparently has useful remarks. For pointwise convergence of $f_n(z)=\dfrac{1}{1+nz}$, clearly for every $z_0\neq0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ we simply write
$$\varepsilon>|f_n(z_0)-0|=\dfrac{1}{|1+nz_0|}\geqslant\dfrac{1}{1+n|z_0|}\geqslant\dfrac{1}{n(1+|z_0|)}$$
then it is sufficient to let $N(\varepsilon,z_0)\geqslant\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon(1+|z_0|)}\rfloor$. Therefore $f_n(z)$ converges pointwise to
$$
f(z)=
\begin{cases}
1&z=0,\\
0&z\neq0.
\end{cases}
$$
and this convergence is not uniform, consider $z_n=\dfrac1n$ so
$$|f_n(z_n)-f(z_n)|=\left|f_n(\dfrac1n)-f(\dfrac1n)\right|=\dfrac12$$
then this convergence isn't uniform for $|z|\leqslant2$, but for $|z|\geqslant2$, then
$$|f_n(z)-0|=\dfrac{1}{|1+nz|}\leqslant\dfrac{1}{n|z|-1}\leqslant\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\leqslant\dfrac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$$
for all $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: Thanks user 108128. I'll analyse later.